# Долгая выгрузка через s3cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3

s3cmd put/sync не поддерживает нативной многопоточности, и выгрузка 6к файлов занимает около 30ти минут, что не очень нравится, хотя сама выгружаемая папка весит 40Мб

`s3cmd sync --recursive /folder s3://bucket/folder/`

Может есть какие-то решения, позволяющие ускорить выгрузку?